# Comparing the `time_total` of two curl requests to different sites

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, curl

I know that I can get the `time_total` of of curl request by using this command:

`curl https://www.google.com -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_total}\n"`

Is there any way for me to easily compare the results of the `time_total` of two sites?

For example, if I have the two commands:

```
curl https://www.google.com -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_total}\n"
curl https://www.yahoo.com -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_total}\n"
```

Rather than running them separately, I'd love to have a single command (i.e. I only have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once) that I can run that would display something like:

```
0.186356 - https://www.google.com
0.535030 - https://www.yahoo.com
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a function for it:

```
speedtest() {
    for url
    do
      curl "$url" -s -o /dev/null -w  "%{time_total} - $url\n"
    done
}
```

Then you can run it on as many urls as you want:

```
$ speedtest https://www.google.com https://www.yahoo.com
0.055323 - https://www.google.com
0.544956 - https://www.yahoo.com
```